# react-native router flux actions.pop() not working right

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have 4 react scenes loader screen, A, B & C. From A I have 2 options to go to B or C. on the opening of my app loader screen is the entry point and it is just a splash screen with a simple loader to initialize my app with dependencies such as Firebase.

B has a function say func1 that does some computation and calls Action.pop() and takes the user to the previous scene.

Situation 1 loaderScreen -> A ->B, func1 is called user is taken back to A. this is the desired flow.

Situation 2 loaderScreen -> A ->C->B , func1 is called user is taken back to the LoaderScreen instead of C (desired effect).

I am using react-native-router-flux@4.0.0-beta.24 for navigation between scenes. I am using react-native v0.49.3

Need help to understand why is this happening

Comment: Can you share your router code? If not, try `Actions.popTo('SceneB')`

Comment: tried doesnt work

Comment: @richTheCreator it was happening as B was a modal type scene and C was added in the stack and for some reason it was not going back to C after popping B. when I took C out of modals and added it back to the stack it worked just fine. I think is a bug in the router flux library

Comment: @richTheCreator I am caught up in another problem please comment on this if u get time to.

link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782942/switching-between-native-and-react-native-flows

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a stack of screens for your pop function to work properly

```
<Stack key='stackOfScreens'>
    <Scene key='SceneA'/>
    <Scene key='SceneB'/>
    <Scene key='SceneC'/>
</Stack>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont reset the stack on the previous screens.

```
Actions.futureScreenName({type:ActionConst.RESET});
```

Cause then you can't pop back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to stack all the scenes together to make the pop work properly between the scenes. Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974416/614902

Answer (score 0):

use this one instead of pop `Actions.replace('SceneName')`